# SharePoint server installation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to know that I have one windows server 2008 R2 configured with TFS 2010, MS SQL 2008 R2 and windows sharepoint service 3.0. Now we need to install sharepoint server 2010 on the same machine.
So can we proceed with same or there can be issues.

Comment: Belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server meets the requirements to support SharePoint Server 2010, there shouldn't be any other compatibility issues, since you are using the latest versions of TFS and MS SQL. Just make sure that the MS SQL version is 2008 R2 64 bits.